# Regular expression to find and replace hyphened class name with a fixed suffix.

Tags: regex

I have this type of divs which similar class , now I wanted to replace all the class with "-type" at the end with regular expression. I have tried this so far http://regexr.com/3b7q3.

```
<div class="form-group form-row @styleProperty username-v-type" data-type="@templateName" data-prop="@styleProperty" data-is-validate="@isValidate">

</div>
```

Comment: So whats happened after you try?

Comment: It selects whole class, I only need to select the classes with -type suffix at the end.

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: Select "...-type" class from the classes values.

Comment: Do you mean `[^ ]*-type"`? http://regexr.com/3b7qc

Comment: Yes. It was also correct @Kasra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to do it by parsing HTML. But you can use this regex instead:

```
 /\b[\w\S]+-type/g
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3b7qf)

Comment: \b[\w\S]+-type" works , thanks.. Or else it will select other data-type attribute

Comment: @RandomIdentity. Hail Anonymity!

Comment: It still selects the data-type attribute as well.

Comment: Yes because it also has a '-type' in the end